# Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'imap' from 'itertools' (unknown location)

Tags: python

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-65-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 
           wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
```

I was under the impression that itertools was already installed? If that's the case, has imap been removed?

The full error message

````
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'imap' from 'itertools' (unknown location)
  File "/address/program.py", line 10, in <module>
    from itertools import imap```
````

Answer (score 1):

The [Python 3 version of `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) doesn't have an `imap()` function, but the [Python 2 version did](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap).

In Python 3 the built-in `map()` function has the same functionality.

My guess is that your code is written in Python 2 but you are trying to (accidentally) run it with Python 3.

Check `python --version`, or, if you want to be absolutely sure, run

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's old code that I'm trying to make python3 compliant.